# ASP.NET MVC 5 custom route does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying for hours to get my custom route to work. I always get a 404 and can't see what I'm doing wrong.

The URL scheme I'm trying to get: /Download/fd39kssdf/myfile.zip.

This is the route, defined before the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Download",
            url: "Download/{hash}/{name}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Download", action = "Index"}
        );
```

This is the code in the controller named "DownloadController":

```
public ActionResult Index(string hash, string name)
    {

    }
```

I have tried adding the parameters to the route with UrlParameter.Optional and "", but neither does work.

Where is the error?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have other routes? Is this defined before the default route?

Comment: It is defined before the default route and I currently have only this route and the default route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is that the IIS has file extensions mapped directly, so your request isn't even being passed over to the ASP.NET handler for processing.  It's actually looking for a myfile.zip in that directory, which doesn't exist giving you the 404 error.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Download-MVC"
         path="/Download/*"
         verb="*"
         type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
         preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You are a genius! ;-) Thank you very much! The problem is absolutely clear now, but I would never have thought of that. Works perfectly!

Comment: You're very welcome.  If you don't mind, please accept my answer since that worked for you.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to vote up but that didn't work because I haven't enough reputation. Then I didn't try to accept the answer. Did it now!